# Configure function from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a function that looks like this :

```
const comparer = (otherArray) => {
  return function (current) {
    return (
      otherArray.filter(function (other) {
        return (
          other.Random_1== current.Random_1 &&
          other.Random_2 ==
            current.Random_2 
            ...
        );
      }).length == 0
    );
  };
};
```

I want to make it configurable from a JSON file like this :

```
{
     "matchingRules": {
         "rule_1" : "other.Random_1 == current.Random_1",
         "rule_2" : "other.Random_2 == current.Random_2",
         ...
     }
}
```

And replace the hardcoded rules in the function with the data from the JSON file. How can I make something like this work ?

Comment: is this what you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval ?

Comment: `eval( json.matchingRules.rule_1) && eval(json.matchingRules.rule_2)`

Comment: eval is risky, use at your own risk

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```js
const identifiers = {
    "rules": {
        "Random_1": "Random_1",
        "Random_2": "Random_2",
    }
}

const comparer = (otherArray) => {
    return function (current) {
        return (
            otherArray.filter(function (other) {
                const entries = Object.entries(identifiers.rules);
                const conditions = entries.map((k, v) => (
                    k == v
                ));
                return conditions.indexOf(false) === -1;
            }).length == 0
        );
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As @ilkerkaran points out, you could use `eval()` to execute snippets of Javascript dynamically loaded from JSON, but that would introduce a large security risk into your code: those snippets could do anything!

It would be safer if you can constrain the structure of your JSON, to only allow certain types of test:

```
{
  "matchingRules": {
    "rule_1" : {
       "field_1": "Random_1",
       "field_2": "Random_1",
       "test": "=="
    },
    "rule_2" : {
       "field_1": "Random_2",
       "field_2": "Random_2",
       "test": ">"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

While that would make your comparison function slightly more complicated to implement, it means that you can test whether `field_1` and `field_2` are actually valid properties of `current` and `other`, do any necessary conversion from string to other types, check their values are valid, and check whether `test` is a valid comparison for your application.  Obviously you don't have to implement the `test` part if you're only interested in testing for equality.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `eval` function

```js
const matchingRules = {
  "rule_1": "other.Random_1 == current.Random_1",
  "rule_2": "other.Random_2 == current.Random_2",
}
const other = {
  Random_1: 10,
  Random_2: 20
}

const current = {
  Random_1: 10,
  Random_2: 200
}

console.log(eval(matchingRules.rule_1));
console.log(eval(matchingRules.rule_2));
```